# SocketTimeoutException is thrown while calling cxf api

Tags: java, timeout, cxf, socket-timeout-exception

SocketTimeoutException is regularly thrown when i try to call the following JAX-RS webservice:

```
while (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty((results = resultAPIService.getResultsByCampaignId(campaign.getId(), pageNumber, MAX_RESULT_SIZE)).getResults())) { ...
```

with `MAX_RESULT_SIZE=100`
and results a object containing a list of Result (15 fields)

On the server side, I have the following cxf configuration:

```
<http:conduit name="{http://XXX/}*.http-conduit">
  <http:client CacheControl="no-store" Connection="Keep-Alive" AllowChunking="false"/>
</http:conduit>
```

which means ReceiveTimeout=-1 (no timeout).

This is the stacktrace:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: Problem with reading the data, class com.xxx.commons.persistence.model.PaginatedEntities, ContentType: application/json.
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.reportMessageHandlerProblem(ResponseImpl.java:438)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:378)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.readBody(AbstractClient.java:517)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.handleResponse(ClientProxyImpl.java:762)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:705)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:227)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy214.getPendingCampaignExecutionResultsByCampaignId(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor407.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:414)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:327)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy215.getPendingCampaignExecutionResultsByCampaignId(Unknown Source)
at com.xxx.yyy.service.job.CampaignActionJob.takeActionOnCampaign(CampaignActionJob.java:144)
at com.xxx.yyy.service.job.CampaignActionJob.lambda$null$0(CampaignActionJob.java:88)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
at com.xxx.yyy.service.job.CampaignActionJob.lambda$execute$1(CampaignActionJob.java:88)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
at com.xxx.yyy.service.job.CampaignActionJob.execute(CampaignActionJob.java:82)
at com.xxx.sdk.quartz.job.DelegateJob.execute(DelegateJob.java:38)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Read timed out (through reference chain: com.xxx.commons.persistence.model.PaginatedEntities["results"]->java.util.ArrayList[10])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:189)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:266)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:217)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:25)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:520)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:258)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1470)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:912)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:811)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1340)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:369)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.fastRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.loadMore(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:180)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._matchToken2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2765)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._matchToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2745)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextFieldName(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1040)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:265)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
```

Is 100 results too much?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: how are you making this call to your web service? is the caller on the same host as the server? does the web service + port appear 'up' and visible to the caller? (for ex: can you `telnet <web service> <port>` from caller's side?)

Comment: caller is host on a different server. I am able to call other web services without any issue so I guess it is not an infrastructure pb.

Comment: the other web services you called on this server that worked -- they use the same db, too?

Comment: @melgart yes, they do

Comment: How long does it take to run your service (approximately)?

Comment: Check configured timeout on client side.